# Is it possible to set Json.Net annotation attribute on class for NullValueHandling?

Tags: .net, json.net

I have a class with a lot of properties, many of them can have null value. I am serializing this class using JSON.NET and I would like to leave out those properties with null value.

For property per property basis I could do:

```
public class MyClass
{
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
   object property1;
       .
       .
       . 
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling=NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
   object property346;
}
```

But this is very tedious, hard to maintain and reduces readability. Is there a way to set annotation on a whole class making it ignore properties with null  values while serializing. I do want to be able to do that via annotations and not in code.

Comment: There's no such setting in [`[JsonObjectAttribute]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm).  You could do it with a custom attribute and a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) - but the custom contract resolver would need to be implemented in code.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation, it does not seem that `JsonObjectAttribute` offers a way to do this. However, you can add your configuration to an extension method, which changes serialization settings depending on the object being serialized.

```
public static string ToJsonString(this object obj)
{
    Type[] objectWithoutNulls = { typeof(MyClass) };
    bool isWithoutNulls = objectWithoutNulls.Contains(obj.GetType());

    if (isWithoutNulls)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
    }
    else
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it on all objects like:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();
var myObject = new Object();

var myClassJson = myClass.ToJsonString(); // Will remove nulls.
var myObjectJson = myObject.ToJsonString();  // Will not remove nulls.
```

Now you have a single place where you can add your configuration for all objects.

Comment: This is not an annotation.

Comment: @user6694745 Sorry, I misread the question. I offered an alternative way on doing it, as it looks like the `ObjectAttribute` does not seem to offer away to do it.

Comment: I already know about alternative way. That is way I specifically asked if there exists some annotation option to avoid writing code, Which in my case I cannot do.

Comment: You can see on this page that it lists all the attributes available for objects and properties. If `JsonObjectAttribute` does not have what you are looking for, then it is highly likely it does not exit. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm